# Is there a relationship between thickness of matter and luminance?

Tags: optics

I'm searching for a relationship between thickness of matter and luminance.

I'm a tribologist and I'm doing friction and wear experiments. During these experiments I'm illuminating the surface and capturing images during the whole test. The incoming light is a diffused light generated by a lighting dome. I'm observing how the pixels that are directed to the surface are getting darker over time due to wear debris deposition.

From what I'm understanding is that the pixel value of each image represent some kind of an uncalibrated luminance value. And my surface is getting darker due to attenuation of radiation (Beers Law). Therefore, is it possible to establish a relationship between Beers Law and luminance?

What I've found so far:

(1) Attenuation of radiation:
$$I(d) = I_0  e^{-\epsilon d},$$
while $\epsilon$ refers to absorption coefficient, $d$ to the material thickness, $I_0$ to the incoming luminous flux and *I(d)* the transmitted luminous flux.

(2) Lambertian reflection:
$$L = (E R)/\pi,$$
while $L$ refers to the luminance, $E$ to the illuminance and $R$ to the reflectance.
As $E=I_0/A$,
$$L = (I_0 R)/(A \pi),$$
while $A$ refers to the surface area.

I believe there is some kind of a relationship that could link the thickness of the deposited materials to the luminance, maybe like this
$$L(d) = L_0 e^{-\varepsilon d} + L_1$$.

So far, I could not find any link that come close to this relationship. I'm I on the wrong path? Thanks for any help!